# Where does The Soldier take place in the timeline?

Tags: polity-universe

Several sources show the latest Polity novel ("*The Soldier*" Rise of the Jain Part 1) as happening ***after*** *Orbus*, but the name used by the Prador King and the description of his physical appearance (at least in a VR conversation with the Earth Central) suggest that it happens before *Orbus* (although clearly after *Line War*). Anyone know the definitive answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neal Asher was asked this in an AMA (ask me anything) thread over on reddit. His answer was that it happens after *Line War* but before the *Spatterjay series*. Therefore, it would appear the book takes place before *Orbus*.

> [**biforcate**](https://www.reddit.com/user/biforcate): Can’t wait to start this new series! Would Line War be the best book to read first to catch up on events before reading The Soldier? (i.e. where does The Soldier fit in the polity timeline?)
>
> [**nealasher**](https://www.reddit.com/user/nealasher): You could simply pick up Line War and read the last few pages. It fits in about a hundred years after them, when Orlandine has built up a defence sphere around the Jain-infested accretion disc. These events occur neatly between the Cormac series and the Spatterjay trilogy.
>
> <sup>[reddit, r/sciencefiction, I'm Neal Asher Science Fiction Writer AMA!](https://www.reddit.com/r/sciencefiction/comments/8jn3kw/im_neal_asher_science_fiction_writer_ama/dz0wqy5/)</sup>